# Emulating multipe nodes on single node in Java?

Tags: java, linux

I evaluate methods to setup and simulate multiple nodes of a virtual cluster on a single computer for cluster emulation in Java.

I might be able to assign virtual hosts /ips and spawn multiple JVM child processes but what is the best way to test cluster behavior to setup and test that kind of behavior.

Every idea to do so is appriciated.

Can I use the same ports for different local ip alias all mapping to a single localhost?

[update]

To give you an idea:

Laptop Dual Core, 8GB, 120GB SSD.

Virtual IPs: 127.0.0.2, ... 127.0.0.11
Now I would love to be able to start java child processes like:
java -jar node.jar  + args = 127.0.0.2 for a node using 127.0.0.2 IP only.

A fall back would be to use different base ports for communication but this will introduce an additional layer and it would feel like testing independent node services running on the same node since it will not envolve the usual cluster detection and forming.

Comment: How about creating 2-3 virtual machines using vmplayer or virtual box.

Comment: That will require up-front configuration, iso management and everything. This is the fall back solution. What I look for is a way to map virtual IP and Ports so each JavaVM feels like a different node but actually shares CPU, RAM and SSD. This might limit auto configuration features but eases testing and even deployment.

Comment: For example my Dev laptop only has 2 cores making it (as far as I know) impossible to create 10 nodes on the fly for testing.

Comment: Which application server are you using and trying to cluster ?

Comment: I use embedded Jetty and jGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that jGroups has everything I need right build in. Just create multiple channel with the same name and live with the logic identity (address) and use other means of identify the actual nodes than IP.

I started and simulated about 1000 nodes each joining three or four channels. It takes about <10ms to join a channel. I even managed to use my four cores to parallelize it. So it takes two to three seconds to start the test. By also forming an alternative channel and disconnect at once from the main channel I was even able to check split brain behavior.

Answer (score 0):

if a simulation environment is an option for you how about trying [cloudsim](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/examples.html)... with a quick look at example 2 and the rest you might find what you are looking for and its java as what you need to import your code.

Comment: It does not fit my requirements.